# Difference between serverURL and publicServerURL on ParseServer

Tags: node.js, parse-server

When using Parser-Server, we use this kind of code to initialize the server:

```
var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: .....,
  cloud: .....,
  appId: .....,
  ..........
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'https://myapp.herokuapp.com/parse',
  publicServerURL: process.env.PARSE_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL || 'https://myapp.herokuapp.com/parse',
  ..........
});
```

I noticed that in some cases the lines `serverURL:` and `publicServerURL:` do not need to be both present.
But here is what I need to know, that I could not find by a simple googling.

What is the exact function of the two parameters `serverURL` and `publicServerURL`?

What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 6):

`serverUrl` is used in cloud code, to communicate back to your parse-server instance. This URL can point to a locally accessible address.
`publicServerURL` is used primarily for files and email verification and should be publicly accessible.

Comment: OK. Thank you. I am just having problem with email verification when creating an account (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49206670/link-inside-verification-mail-not-working) so publicServerURL may well be the issue?

Comment: most probably, note that the public server URL should point to an accessible parse server.

Comment: I indeed made sure that was not the issue, but unfortunately it does not solve the problem as you can see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49206670/link-inside-verification-mail-not-working

Comment: is your app mounted on `/` or on `/parse`?

Comment: I will check that. How do I see if my app is mounted on / or on /parse?
I know it all works fine except for this issue. And I don't remember I have consciously made this choice of mounting on one or the other. I probably  have used whatever the default is.

Comment: I have these two line in my index.js file:
1) var mountPath = process.env.PARSE_MOUNT || '/parse';
2) app.use(mountPath, api);

Comment: I also noticed that this https://myapp.herokuapp.com/apps/ is not working. It displays: "Cannot GET /apps/".

Comment: OK. But in either case it does not work.
- Case 1)
publicServerURL: .... 'https://myapp.herokuapp.com/parse',
The error is:
{"error":"unauthorized"}
- Case 2)
publicServerURL: .... 'https://myapp.herokuapp.com',
The error is:
Cannot GET /apps/....

Comment: I can understand the error: {"error":"unauthorized"}. But what is this "Cannot GET /apps/..." about? I don't see any /apps in my index.js.